# Spark-shell failed to start with exception:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: apache-spark, exception, spark-shell

I'm new to Spark, installed several machines, runs `spark-shell` OK. But on one of my machines (RHEL5, a bit old), I got problem:

I've installed JDK, Scala, Ppark from tar.gz files as below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/me/software/jdk1.8.0_181
export SCALA_HOME=/home/me/software/scala-2.11.0
export SPARK_HOME=/home/me/software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I tried `spark-shell` and it gives:

```
$spark-shell
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2467)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2467)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2467)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$doPrepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:416)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doPrepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:132)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:39)
    ... 28 more
```

What does this error indicate? How can I trouble shoot and fix it?

Comment: Look at the last `Caused by` because the "reflection" stuff just means that a generic framework called a generic pointer to an anonymous function, WTF.

Comment: `JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative` >> JNI (Java Native Interface) hints that a Java library is trying to bind an OS library -- or any other C library (i.e. a `.so`) ; `UnixGroupsMapping` implies that the Hadoop client lib tries to resolve authorizations by checking which Linux groups the process user belings to.

Comment: Well-known pain in the ass: some jerk included client-side unit tests for Hadoop-server-side-only features. Hence you need a full set of "native libs" client-side that will never be used. It's particularly painful on Windows with Kerberos authentication...